# Android Folder structure (classes, ...)

Tags: java, android, structure, directory

I've started a few days ago to programming android apps. Now I want to use a "correct" folder structure. I want to make class's, but where I have to place them? In the `app/java/overbit.user` folder? It would be nice if you could give me some advice.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, under `app/java/overbit.user`, just like your `MainActivity` class is.

Of course, you can make subfolders like `logic.model`, `ui` etc. to keep project organized.

I recommend you to read [Managing Projects Overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have one more question. I need for every layout file a activity file?

Comment: @MyNewName In very early days of Android, every screen came with new Activity. Now, most people use `Fragment` class to create screens (including me). Folder `layout` doesn't contain only screen views, but things like rows for adapters too. You don't need layout file, but it's much easier to create complicated layout with many components inside using XML, instead of writing Java code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! I will take a look at `Fragment` classes

Comment: @MyNewName You can read basic things how to build UI using `Fragment` on official Android pages like http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is always good practice to keep classes in separate package i.e creating folders and keep the similar type of tasks inside same package. Which will allow your application to be more readable and easy to understand modules in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean with package? `oberbit.user` is the package? And you create inside this package other "packages" (alias folders (?))?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm using a package for Classes like my `Settings classes` on it.

So, the answer is yes, you should/can use or create a package for those classes if they are so many.

**Under:**

```
app/java/overbit.user
```

Of course, you can take a look at this project on **Github**:

https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/tree/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram

**Edit:**

as you can see, that project has packages for :

- PhoneFormat
- SQLite
- messenger
- tgnet
- ui

And every package has a lot of works to do :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer + for the example! :)

Comment: Happy programming :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is Main Structure of Android Application
[image]